# Difference between ${v^^} and ${v@U}?

Tags: bash, terminal, parameter-expansion

Bash 4 had parameter expansion operations which allowed to convert string stored in variable to upper/lower case using `${v^}`, `${v^^}`, `${v,}`, or `${v,,}`. In Bash 5 new `@` notation was added to provide various expansion operations, some of which also include case conversions: `${v^}` == `${v@u}`, `${v^^}` == `${v@U}`, `${v,,}` == `${v@L}` (no matching operator for `${v,}` it seems).

What is the difference between `${v^^}` and `${v@U}`, and for what purpose new operators that do the same thing were added?

Comment: Just a random guess: they have been added because they are easier to remember?

Answer (score 2):

Expansions like `${x^^}` take an optional pattern (that should match a single character at a time; it defaults to `?` if omitted) that controls which characters are upper cased, while `${x@U}` upper cases *all* characters. If you leave out the pattern in the first form they're equivalent, but if you specify one they're not the same. `${x^^[aeiou]}` will only uppercase vowels, for example.

Comment: I have no clue as to the rational for the new expansions considering the old ones can do the same thing, though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the code eventually end in the same function `sh_modcase`.

`^^` and the family is expanded in `parameter_brace_casemod`, while the newer syntax is expanded in `string_transform`.

Looking at `string_transform` it's evident that other transformations are also possible:

```c
  switch (xc)
    {
      /* Transformations that interrogate the variable */
      case 'a':
    i = var_attribute_string (v, 0, flags);
    ret = (i > 0) ? savestring (flags) : (char *)NULL;
    break;
      case 'A':
    ret = string_var_assignment (v, s);
    break;
      case 'K':
    ret = sh_quote_reusable (s, 0);
    break;
      /* Transformations that modify the variable's value */
      case 'E':
    t = ansiexpand (s, 0, strlen (s), (int *)0);
    ret = dequote_escapes (t);
    free (t);
    break;
      case 'P':
    ret = decode_prompt_string (s);
    break;
      case 'Q':
    ret = sh_quote_reusable (s, 0);
    break;
      case 'U':
    ret = sh_modcase (s, 0, CASE_UPPER);
    break;
      case 'u':
    ret = sh_modcase (s, 0, CASE_UPFIRST);  /* capitalize */
    break;
      case 'L':
    ret = sh_modcase (s, 0, CASE_LOWER);
    break;
      default:
    ret = (char *)NULL;
    break;
    }
```